# What does "Quick Upload" do?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, images, gallery

Using Motorola Atrix with Android 2.3.

When long-clicking an image in the Gallery (Galerie in German), among others there’s an option to “Quick Upload” (“Schnelles Hochladen” in German). What does this option do? It seems to do something for a while, but then it doesn’t tell me anything.

The first time I used it it asked for an e-mail address. I specified my Gmail address, assuming that it would upload the images to the relevant Google account. But I can’t find them anywhere.

It’s the fourth option in this screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the translation is `Instant upload`, and it means that it uploads the photo to your Google+ account's Instant Uploads album in the background. Check your g+ profile for this folder.

Comment: Well, but it doesn’t. I’ve checked all over Google+, especially the albums. There’s nothing there. (There’s also no indication of uploading in the background.)